# Confused about when to use `bind` in an Event Handler

Tags: javascript, this

The following successfully prints 'foo'.

```
var obj = {
    name: 'foo',
    printName: function printName() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  };

var printButton= document.getElementById('printIt');

printButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  obj.printName(); 
});
```

The following doesn't, however:

```
printButton.addEventListener('click', obj.printName() );
```

I know the solution... simply use `bind` so that we're referencing the `obj` object. i.e:

```
printButton.addEventListener('click', obj.printName.bind(obj) );
```

Why then don't we need to use `bind` in the first example. I don't know why wrapping `obj.printName()` function call in the anonymous function results in the `console.log` correctly referencing and printing `this` properly, but when called directly after `click`, you needs to use `bind`

Comment: This isn't exactly a full answer, but I wanted to point out something that many new js programmers (and myself at times) forget: functions are first class citizens meaning there is a difference between 1) `obj.printName` and 2) `obj.printName()`. 1) the value of this expression is the function itself and this is what you pass to the `addEventListener` method. 2) this expression invokes the function and therefore the value of the expression is the value that the function itself returns. in this case, that value is `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Another thing to note is that *invoking* bind actually returns another function that you could invoke like `obj.printName.bind(obj)()`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I commented with some good information on this question so I might as well answer!

## Functions are first class

Okay, let's starts with some fundamentals of javascript that is very dissimilar to some other programming languages: in javascript functions are *first class citizens*--which is just a fancy way of saying that you can save functions into variables and you can pass functions into other functions.

```
const myFunction = function () { return 'whoa a function'; }
array.map(function () { return x + 1; });
```

And because of this wonderful feature, there is a big difference between the expressions:

**Expression 1**

```
obj.printName
```

and

**Expression 2**

```
obj.printName();
```

In expression 1: the function isn't being invoked so the value of the expression is of type `function`

In expression 2: the function is being invoked so the value of the expression is what the function returns. In your case, that's `undefined`

---

## `addEventListener`

The method `addEventListener` takes in two arguments:

1. a `string` of the type of event
2. a `function` that will be run when the event fires.

Alight, so what does that mean?

When you call

```
// doesn't work
printButton.addEventListener('click', obj.printName() );
```

you're not passing a value of type `function` to the `addEventListener` method, you're actually passing `undefined`.

```
// works
printButton.addEventListener('click', obj.printName.bind(obj) );
```

then works (for one reason) because the second argument is actually of type `function`.

---

## What does `bind` do? Why does it return a function?

Now we need to discuss what `bind` actually does. It related to the pointer* `this`.

*by pointer, I mean a reference identifier to some object

**`bind` is a method that exists on every function object that simply binds the `this` pointer of a desired object to the function**

This is best shown by an example:

Say you have a class `Fruit` that has a method `printName`. Now that we know that you can save a method into a variable, let's try that. In the example below we're assigning two things:

1. `boundMethod` which used `bind`
2. `unboundMethod` that didn't use `bind`

```js
class Fruit {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'apple';
  }
  
  printName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

const myFruit = new Fruit();

// take the method `printName`
const boundMethod = myFruit.printName.bind(myFruit);
const unboundMethod = myFruit.printName;

boundMethod(); // works
unboundMethod(); // doesn't work
```

**So what happens when you don't call `bind`?** Why doesn't that work?

If you don't call bind in this case, the value of the function that gets stored into the identifier `unboundMethod` can be thought to be:

```
// doens't work
const unboundMethod = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

where the contents of the function is the same contents of the method `printName` from the `Fruit` class. Do you see why this is an issue?

*Because the `this` pointer is still there but the object it was intended to refer to is no longer in scope.* When you try to invoke the `unboundMethod`, you'll get an error because it couldn't find `name` in `this`.

**So what happens when you do use `bind`?**

*Loosely* `bind` can be thought of as replacing the `this` value of function with the object you're passing into `bind`.

So if I assign: `myFruit.printName.bind(myFruit)` to `boundMethod` then you can think of the assignment like this:

```
// works
const boundMethod = function() {
    console.log(myFruit.name);
}
```

where `this` is replaced with `myFruit`

## The bottom-line/TL;DR

> when to use `bind` in an Event Handler

You need to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) when you want to replace the `this`es inside the function with another object/pointer. **If your function doesn't ever use `this`, then you don't need to use `bind`.**

> Why then don't we need to use bind in the first example?

**If you don't need to "take the method" (i.e. taking the value of type of `function`), then you don't need to use `bind` either** Another way to word that is: if you invoke the method directly from the object, you don't need `bind` that same object.

In the wrapper function, you're directly invoking the method of the object (as in expression 2). Because you're invoking the method without "taking the method" (we "took" the methods into variables in the Fruit example), you don't need to use `bind`.

```
printButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // directly invoke the function
  // no method "taking" here
  obj.printName();
});
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Wow, this is a really thoughtful post. I understand when to use 'this', but I still don't understand why I don't need to use ' bind' when wrapped in a function. Both are technically callbacks.

Comment: @Modermo well, you don't need to use bind when wrapped in a function because the function you just wrote doesn't use `this`. it's an easy way to think about it: If your function doesn't ever use `this`, then you don't need to use bind.

Comment: thanks for being patient with me, I'm new to JS. The thing is, I am using 'this' in the 'printName' function. Do you mean the wrapper function doesn't use 'this'? Because the function I'm calling does use 'this'

Comment: @Modermo i think i misunderstood you, I updated my answer to directly answer your question.

Comment: @Modermo yeah check out my updated answer. my apologizes for the many updates. wording and explaining programming needs to be just as precise as programming itself lol

Comment: I think I need to do some more research, because I just can't seem to figure this out right now. The way that I see it, whether wrapping in a function or immediately invoking right after the event type, the value of `this` in both is not that of the `obj` (unless of course you use `bind`). What do you mean by "method taking"?

Comment: @Modermo I just mean "taking" it as in assigning the value of the function itself to a variable or passing the value of the function itself as an argument to another function. Lack of a better word, sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: You need to call `printButton.addEventListener('click', obj.printName() );` without parenthesis in `obj.printName()` since you want to pass the function.

The answer lies in the way `this` is bound in Javascript. In JS, the way a function is called decides how `this` is bound. So when you provide the callback function like below:

```
printButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  obj.printName(); 
});
```

Notice, printName is being called via `dot` notation. This is called implicit binding rule when `this` is bound to an object before dot, in this case `obj`. Clearly in this case, you get the expected output.

However, when you call it like this:

```
printButton.addEventListener('click', obj.printName );
```

Notice that, all you are passing is the `address` of the function that is inside obj. So in this case info about obj is lost. In other words, the code that calls back the function doesn't have the info about obj that could have been used to set `this`. All it has is the address of the function to call.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**:
Look at this `crude` implementation I call `bind2` that mimics native bind. This is just to illustrate how native `bind` function returns a new function.

```
Function.prototype.bind2 = function (context) {
        var callBackFunction = this;//Store the function to call later
        return function () {        //return a new function
            callBackFunction.call(context);//Later when called, apply 
                                           //context, this is `obj` passed 
                                           //in bind2()
        }
    };

    function hello() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
    obj = {
        name:'ABC'
    };
    var f = hello.bind2(obj);


    f();
```

**Notice**: How function f() is `hard bound` here. f() has hard bound `this` with `obj`. You cannot change `this` to other than `obj` now. This is another thing with bind that probably will help you knowing.

Comment: No, `printButton.addEventListener('click', obj.printName() );` also passes `obj` as `this`. It just doesn't register `printName` as a click handler, it calls it immediately.

Comment: @melpomene, yeah I think that is different issue, maybe a typo. He just needs to pass the function reference.

Comment: *this* is not "context". Using dot notation is just one way to set a function's *this*, there are many others (*call*, *apply*, *bind*, *new*, lexically in arrow functions, maybe others…).